# facing this error in react "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm facing the "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')" issue. I attached the code.
Thank you in Advance

```
       switch (action.type) {
case "CART_ADD_ITEM":
  const newItem = action.payload;
  const existItem = state.cartItems.find(
    (item) => item._id === newItem._id
  );
  const cartItems = existItem
    ? state.cart.cartItems.map((item) =>
        item._id === existItem._id ? newItem : item
      )
    : [...state.cart.cartItems, newItem];
  return {
    ...state,
    cart: {
      ...state.cart,
      cartItems,
    },
  };
```

[image: error image]

Comment: *I attached the code* No, you did not.

Comment: Can you include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that it is easier to debug your code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your array has some empty slots. So attempting to check `item.id` will throw an error. Just check that the item exists first.

```js
    const existItem = test.find((item) => {
      if (item) item._id === newItem._id;
    });
```